# Christoffel symbols in normal coordinates

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, coordinate-systems, curvature, geodesics

I'm confused by the proof of $\Gamma^\lambda{_{\mu \nu}}(p) = 0$ in the normal coordinates.

Let $p \in M$ be a point with an orthonormal basis $e_a$, and one considers the exponential map $\exp_p: T_p M \to M$. A point $\exp_p(\lambda X)$ near $p$ has coordinate value $x^a(\exp_p(\lambda X)) = \lambda X^a$ for $X = X^a e_a \in T_p M$.

Varying $\lambda$, $\exp_p(\lambda X)$ becomes a geodesic, and therefore satisfy **along the geodisic**,
$$
\frac{d^2 x^a}{d\lambda^2} + \Gamma^a{_{bc}}\frac{dx^b}{d\lambda}\frac{dx^c}{d\lambda} = 0 \ .
$$
Here $x^a(\lambda) = \lambda X^a$, and therefore **I think**
$$
0 + \Gamma^a{_{bc}}X^b X^c = 0 \ ,\text{ along } \exp_p(λX) \ .
$$
Given that $X$ is arbitrary, I seem to conclude that $\Gamma^a{_{bc}} = 0$ along any geodesic and therefore in a neighborhood of $p$, which is of course wrong. **I wonder where I made a mistake?**

Comment: $\Gamma(\gamma(s)))$ depends on the point $\gamma(s)$ along the chosen geodesic $\gamma$, whereas your reasoning holds true for $s=0$ only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're making a mistake in seeing $X$ as arbitrary: you should see it as the "basis vector" of $x$, which isn't arbitrary, because it's the specific vector that tells you, from the origin of your normal coordinates, where to go to reach the point $p$.

The proof can then be concluded as follows:
$$\text{from}\quad \Gamma^a_{bc}X^b X^c=0\quad \Rightarrow\quad\Gamma^a_{bc}x^b x^c=0\quad\text{you derive twice and obtain}$$
$$\partial_\alpha\partial_\beta\Gamma^a_{bc}x^b x^c+2\partial_\beta\Gamma^a_{\alpha c}x^c+2\partial_\alpha\Gamma^a_{\beta c}x^c+2\Gamma^a_{\alpha\beta}=0$$
$$\text{and, in the origin of your coordinates, when}\quad x=0, \Rightarrow \Gamma^a_{\alpha\beta}=0 \qquad\Box$$